Hyperlink in excel with partial pdf file name
I have incoming correspondence log in excel and given hyperlink to pdf files manually. Each files will start with reference number + subject of the correspondence, eg.: 125 - Saturday Working Schedule, 126 - Minutes of Meeting.
File Path & Files.
I tried to create a hyperlink taking partial name (reference number) & adding asterisk() for example
=HYPERLINK("\D:\EXCEL FORMULA & WORKOUT\sample works\hyperlink samples"&A3&".pdf", B3). it didn't work.
log
I tried this below, it works
with hyperlink
but...
in somes cases i may rename the pdf file (subject) name in short to avoid long filename and in excel log i may give the full subject name...and there my formula doesn't works.
So, please help me to get the hyperlink formula in VBA using partial name in Column "E".
Thank you...
